# Placing multiple images in divs over another div

Tags: css

I am trying to put together a navigation bar that looks like this:

http://s7.postimage.org/jhfi6rbp7/gallerybar.jpg

All of the squares are separate images that I want to align to the left of a div tag containing the orange bar .jpg.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div id="rule">
    <img src="../images/rule2.jpg" width="750" height="1" >
    <div id="   gallery">
        <img src="../images/portfolio/gallery_bplogo_active.jpg" alt="Logo Design"        width="112" height="112"/>
        <img src="../images/portfolio/gallery_bpprint.jpg" width="112" height="112" alt="Magazine and Newspaper Ads" />
        <img src="../images/portfolio/gallery_bpradio.jpg" width="112" height="112" alt="Radio Spot" />
        <img src="../images/portfolio/gallery_bptelevision.jpg" width="112" height="112" alt="TV Spot" />
        <img src="../images/portfolio/gallery_bpvehiclewrap.jpg" width="112" height="112" />
    </div>
</div>

#rule {
    border:0;
    text-align: center;
}

#gallery {
    height: 115px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 20 px;
    border-color:#FFF;
}
```

I can't figure out how to vertically center the images on the bar - they insist on floating just beneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solution http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdanek/CN3Tb/

```
#gallery {
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#gallery img { 
    position: relative; 
    background: #fff;
}

#gallery:before { 
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border: 1px solid orange;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

<div id="gallery">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="112" height="112">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="112" height="112">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="112" height="112">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="112" height="112">
</div>
```

I’ve removed unnecessary markup and simplified your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#gallery img {float: left; margin-right: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image needs to be aligned within the img tag.

```
img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```